# Mirror modifier makes mirror-plane faces when modifier "Realtime Display" togglebutton is off

Tags: mirror-modifier

In Blender 2.93.1: when extruding and insetting in context of a mirror modifier (with 'clipping' checked), normally, no faces are created in the mirror-plane.

But, I discovered that when the Modifier's "Show in viewport" ((1) in screenshot) toggle button is off ...

[image]

... extruding *does* make mirror plane faces, messing up further symmetric modelling. Later, I found that when toggling "View in Edit mode" ((2) in earlier screenshot) instead, will correctly not create mirror plane faces.

See screenshot below: on top is made with button (2) off, while bottom one is made with button (1) toggled off.

[image]

One would expect a merely visual toggle feature should not influence the actual modelling. Is this by design? And if so, what is the reasoning?